# Running cordova platform add ubuntu failes

Tags: cordova

I am following official docs from documentation [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/index.html#installing-the-development-environment) to build a test procject, but I am getting a following error.

```
cordova platform add ubuntu
Using cordova-fetch for ubuntu@^2.0.0
Adding ubuntu project...
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module '/home/adam/projects/helloworld/node_modules/ubuntu'
(node:25739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (The platform "ubuntu" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ubuntu not supported.)
```

What am I missing? Thanks

I am running Ubuntu 17.10, and Cordova 8.0.0

Comment: ubuntu platform is deprecated, try with previous CLI (7.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

as per Cordova's blog they are deprecating ubuntu as a supporting platform from version 8 onwards

https://cordova.apache.org/blog/